# Convert Linux's curl program to a python code

Tags: python, csv, curl

I need to convert the following curl program to equivalent python program and also want to know how to store the response of this request which is a csv file in python.

curl --data-binary @obama.txt "http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassify?query=obama"

This is a program used for calculating sentiment score for each tweet in the text file obama.txt.

ex: obama.txt may contain:
\n obama is awesome
\n I do not know who is obama
\n obama is eating a potato

(\n = new line)

the --data-binary flag tells curl to preserve the new line character in the sent data set, and the @obama.txt tells curls which filename to read the data from

The response will be a CSV with two fields:
-polarity. The polarity values are:
    0: negative
    2: neutral
    4: positive
-the text

How can I possibly implement the same functionality in python. I have very less experience in using python so if someone can give the exact code then it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library

```
>>> import requests
>>> with open('obama.txt','r') as f:
...     text = f.read()
... 
>>> r=requests.post('http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassify?query=obama',data=text)

>>> print r.text
"4","obama is awesome"
"2","I do not know who is obama"
"2","obama is eating a potato"
```